# A regular hexagon is tiled with diamonds in three orientations. Prove that the same number of tiles appear in each orientation.

Tags: geometry, puzzle

> A large regular hexagon is cut out of a triangular grid and tiled with diamonds (pairs of triangles glued together along an edge). Diamonds come in three varieties, depending on orientation; prove that precisely the same number of each variety must appear in the tiling.

This puzzle is from Gurmeet.net's [Tiling with Calissons](https://gurmeet.net/puzzles/tiling-with-calissons/index.html) puzzle page. The "Proof without Words" solution is accompanied by this image:

[image]

My approach: I tried reading through the solution but it simply blows my mind. The proof without words, how did they even come up with that? Any clue how to start/proceed will help.

Comment: I suspect that coming up with the proof without words follows from letting your brain see the picture on the left in three dimensions. Then you see how it is carved from a cube as in the shaded version on the right, which shows how the left, right and bottom faces are "covered" by the three projections.

Comment: As far as *"[H]ow did they even come up with that?"* ... I have a suspicion that the puzzle was originally devised *based on* the optical illusion.

Comment: There is also some very good answers on [puzzling.se]:  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/12357/ .